# Passing structs to CUDA kernels

Tags: struct, cuda, alignment

I'm new to CUDA C, and am trying to pass a typedef'd struct into a kernel. My method worked fine when I tried it with a struct containing only ints, but when I switch to floats I get meaningless numbers back as results. I assume this has to do with alignment, and I tried including `__align__` along with my type declaration, but to no avail. Can someone give me an example of how this is done, or provide an alternative approach? I'm trying to set it up so that I can easily add or remove fields without changing anything other than the struct and the kernel. My code:

```
typedef struct __align__(8)
{
    float a, b;
} point;

__global__ void testKernel(point *p)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    p[i].a = 1.1;
    p[i].b = 2.2;
}

int main(void)
{
        // set number of points 
    int numPoints    = 16,
        gpuBlockSize = 4,
        pointSize    = sizeof(point),
        numBytes     = numPoints * pointSize,
        gpuGridSize  = numPoints / gpuBlockSize;

        // allocate memory
    point *cpuPointArray = new point[numPoints],
          *gpuPointArray = new point[numPoints];
    cpuPointArray = (point*)malloc(numBytes);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&gpuPointArray, numBytes);

        // launch kernel
    testKernel<<<gpuGridSize,gpuBlockSize>>>(gpuPointArray);

        // retrieve the results
    cudaMemcpy(cpuPointArray, gpuPointArray, numBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("testKernel results:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i)
    {
        printf("point.a: %d, point.b: %d\n",cpuPointArray[i].a,cpuPointArray[i].b);
    }

        // deallocate memory
    free(cpuPointArray);
    cudaFree(gpuPointArray);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the point *gpuPointArray = new... seems wrong to me? You're allocating on host and after that doing a cudaMalloc on the device...

Comment: Don't I need to allocate the memory before passing it as an argument to the kernel? Leaving the cudaMalloc line out gives an "unspecified launch failure." I could also set gpuPointArray to NULL, but it doesn't seem to change my original result.

Comment: Absolutely.  You need the cudaMalloc. You don't need the "new" before it though. Same goes for cpuPointArray. Use malloc and free (you're programming C) and don't use the new here. (Never ever mix new malloc delete and free)

Answer (score 24):

Since there doesn't appear to be any decent documentation on how to do this, I thought I'd post the final, revised code here. It turns out that the `__align__` part was unnecessary as well, the actual problem was the use of %d in the printf when trying to print floats.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    float a, b;
} point;

__global__ void testKernel(point *p)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    p[i].a = 1.1;
    p[i].b = 2.2;
}

int main(void)
{
        // set number of points 
    int numPoints    = 16,
        gpuBlockSize = 4,
        pointSize    = sizeof(point),
        numBytes     = numPoints * pointSize,
        gpuGridSize  = numPoints / gpuBlockSize;

        // allocate memory
    point *cpuPointArray,
          *gpuPointArray;
    cpuPointArray = (point*)malloc(numBytes);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&gpuPointArray, numBytes);

        // launch kernel
    testKernel<<<gpuGridSize,gpuBlockSize>>>(gpuPointArray);

        // retrieve the results
    cudaMemcpy(cpuPointArray, gpuPointArray, numBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("testKernel results:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i)
    {
        printf("point.a: %f, point.b: %f\n",cpuPointArray[i].a,cpuPointArray[i].b);
    }

        // deallocate memory
    free(cpuPointArray);
    cudaFree(gpuPointArray);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at how it's done in the vector_types.h header that comes in your CUDA include directory. That should already give you some pointers.

However, the main problem here is the `%d` in your `printf` calls. You're trying to print floats now, not integers. So those really should use `%f` instead.

Comment: Okay, I've looked at vector_types.h, and I tried doing what they did: `typedef struct __align__(2*sizeof(float)) point {` ..., but it still yields the same result. Is there something else here that I should be seeing?

Comment: By the way, change your printf  to use %f instead of %d...does that change anything? You're trying to print floats now, not ints...

Comment: This answer could have been a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @bamboon. An oldie. It seems I never integrated the actual answer from the comments into the answer. Have done so now. That should make it a bit more of an answer.